# Why does Google Spreadsheets says Zero is not equals Zero?

Tags: google-sheets

After spending hours trying to figure out an error in my personal accounting spreadsheet, I could pin it up to one formula.

While this results in Zero

```
=((0,6-0,3-0,4)+(-0,3+0,8-0,4))
```

comparing it with Zero gives me false

```
=((0,6-0,3-0,4)+(-0,3+0,8-0,4))=0
```

What the heck am I missing?

Comment: Have you never encountered the joys of floating point math?

Comment: Yes I did (in the worse way) with Javascript. But don't Google Spreeadsheets math computation occurs server side?

Comment: Probably. I'm afraid I don't have an answer for you. I just found it a little funny that here's another domain where `0 != 0`.

Comment: Perhaps you could check if it's less than or equal to the smallest number.

Comment: "After spending hours trying to figure out an error in my personal accounting spreadsheet" - love that :D glad I'm not the only person who waste time this way ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to the wonders of [floating-point arithmetics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate),

```
((0.6-0.3-0.4)+(-0.3+0.8-0.4))
```

evaluates to approximately -5.55e-17 in double precision. This holds in JavaScript as well as in Google Spreadsheets. It does not really matter whether the computation is client-side or server-side: what matters is the number format used. It appears that Google Sheets [use double precision](https://nickhigham.wordpress.com/2013/03/13/how-accurate-are-spreadsheets-in-the-cloud/).

The solution is the same: avoid equality comparison for floating point numbers. In your case, changing the units by multiplying everything by 10 would avoid the problem.

Comment: I mentioned "server-side" because Google could use arbitrary precision decimal numeric type from their favorite programming language within their servers.

Comment: There is a platform that uses decimal rather than binary floating point: HP48S.

I worked out that the actual decimal digits are stored in packs of 4 bits, so a but wasteful as not all combinations of 4 bits are used. I remember that I experimented by changing the memory directly and even making digits more than 9.

Comment: My solution was to `=FLOOR(B3+C2, 0.01)` for working with currency